# RabbitMQ headers exchange routing: match all listed headers

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have a lot of consumers with different set of features, so I want route message to process to correct one. I decided use headers exchange and specify necessary features in message headers, but here fall into obstacle.

In rabbitMQ there is binding argument `x-match` which may take values only **any** and **all** (https://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-July/028575.html). Each consumer instead while binds has big list of available features (most of them are true/false, but also there are strings), which I specify as binding arguments along with `x-match` argument. But when I publish message I wanna specify only necessary headers, for instance, *feature-1* and *feature-7* with specific values. I don't even know about all available consumer features when publish the message. And here is problem: if I miss some of binding argument when `x-match==all`, message won't be routed, and if I set `x-match` to `any`, the only matching header is enough to route message - despite another header's value may not match.

To give you example, let's consider consumer with features: `country=US, f1=true, f2=true, f3=false`.

- Scenario 1: So I attach (create binding) its queue to headers exchange with these arguments and `x-match` set to **all**. Then I publish message and I need `country` to be *"US"* and `f2` to be *true*. I don't know anything about other possible consumer features. Message won't be routed, because not all headers match exactly.
- Scenario 2: Another use case is if I bind queue with `x-match` argument set to `any`. If I specify again `country` to be *"US"* and `f2` to be *true* - message will be routed, but also it will be (incorrectly) routed if `f2` is set to *false* and only `country` matches.

So probably I misunderstand something, but I look for easiest solution for me: how to route message to right consumer based on list of necessary features. I would like to use something like `all-specified` value for `x-match` argument which wouldn't demand list all available features but will require all given headers to match exactly.

Comment: a bit sad if only way is to write own exchange. Erlang seems for me to be a kind of magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, only own exchange may help for my purpose. If I'm succeed in erlang I'll report here.

### Update

I managed to write own plugin which fits my purposes. Probably it is not perfect but works good for me for now.

https://github.com/senseysensor/rabbitmq-x-features-exchange

Comment: Great, I'll try this plugin. This functionality is very useful, don't understand why RabbitMQ doesn't have it. @Serge Could you share your experience with this plugin. Did you use it in production?

Comment: hi. Yes, we used it. We didn't have extra high load but we never experienced any issues with it. Actually it is a bit modified headers plugin, I only changed as few code as I could. Unfortunately that project is now abandoned so I don't have fresh stats about that. @smimov